# Increase space between border and background-image

Tags: css, border, background-image

I want to increase the distance between the border and the background-image ... I tried to add `padding: 20px;` but it doesn't work.

```css
.Tab1 {
  background-image: url("http://dl.dg-site.com/wp-content/themes/aeron/images/dl-products-icons5.jpg");
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  display: block;
}
.Tab1:hover {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="Tab1"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **increase the space between the border and the background image** with `padding` and `background-clip:content-box;` (see MDN for [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)).

Also don't forget to center the background image with `background-position:center;`

```css
.Tab1 {
    background-image:url("http://dl.dg-site.com/wp-content/themes/aeron/images/dl-products-icons5.jpg");
    background-position:center;
    width:100px;
    height:73px;
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    background-clip:content-box;
}
.Tab1:hover {
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="Tab1"></div>
```

If you also want to avoid the position snap on hover created by the border, you can add a transparent border and only change the colour on hover :

```css
.Tab1 {
  background-image: url("http://dl.dg-site.com/wp-content/themes/aeron/images/dl-products-icons5.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-clip: content-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  display: block;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.Tab1:hover {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="Tab1"></div>
```

Comment: Ahhh you beat me to it!

Answer (score 2):

```
.Tab1{background-image:url("http://dl.dg-site.com/wp-content/themes/aeron/images/dl-products-icons5.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
 background-clip:content-box;
        width:100px;
        height:75px;
        display:block;
padding:20px;
}

.Tab1:hover{border:1px solid green;}
```

This is what you need, you first align the background to the centre of the box and then add a padding with the padding CSS, as you originally tried to do. The `background-repeat` property will stop the background repeating into the padding of the CSS.

Please also remember to add units to the padding value, just in case you had tried to do what you'd written as adding `padding:20`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check here the space between image and border...

```css
.Tab1{background-image:url("http://dl.dg-site.com/wp-content/themes/aeron/images/dl-products-icons5.jpg");
        width:100px;
        height:75px;
        display:block;
        padding:15px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center center;
        border:1px solid #fff;
    }
.Tab1:hover{border:1px solid green;}
```

```html
<div class="Tab1">
    
    
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
css code     
.Tab1 {   
   background:url("http://dl.dg-site.com/wp-content/themes/aeron/images/dl-products-icons5.jpg");
   background-position:center;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   width:100px;
   height:75px;
   display:block;
   padding:15px;
   }
   .Tab1:hover {   
   border:1px solid green;
   margin-left:-1px;
   margin-top:-1px;
   }
```